# MonoDroid: Getting the Resource .Designer.cs to refresh

Tags: xamarin.android

After I update the XML in a Layout, the **Resource.Designer.cs** does not refresh automatically.

How can I get MonoDroid to update the class so that I get **Intellisence** on new items added/changed in my Activity's layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The designer files get updated as part of the build, so if you rebuild your project after updating your layout they'll get regenerated.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's compiled as AndroidResource, the Resource.Layout.View2 shows up, I can change to it via SetContentView(Resource.Layout.View2), but the textView1 object is not found at all - it's not even in the resource.designer.cs file.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Rebuilding doesn't always work. It's a bug of Mono for Android. Try installing a new version, that may work.